# How to apply shaders and generate images only once?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot-shader-language

I'm trying to apply a pixelation shader to my textures and I need it to be applied only once, after that I can reuse my shader generated images as textures over and over without having to calculate every single time.

so how do I take a few images -> apply a shader and render them only once every time the game loads -> and use them as my textures?

so far I've managed to find the shader to apply:

```
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform int amount = 40;

void fragment()
{
    vec2 grid_uv = round(UV * float(amount)) / float(amount);
    
    vec4 text = texture(TEXTURE, grid_uv);
    
    COLOR = text;
}
```

but I have no idea how to render out the images using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shaders reside in the GPU, and their output goes to the screen. To save the image, the CPU would have to see the GPU output, and that does not happen… Usually. And since it does not go through the CPU, the performance is good. *Usually. Well, at least it is better than if the CPU was doing it all the time.*

*Also, are you sure you don't want to get a pixel art look by other means? Such as removing filter from the texture, changing the stretch mode and working on a small resolution, and perhaps enable pixel snap? No? Watch [How to make a silky smooth camera for pixelart games in Godot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxVQsi9wnw8). Still No? Ok...*

Anyway, for what you want, you are going to need a `Viewport`.

---

### Viewport setup

What you will need is to create a `Viewport`. *Don't forget to set its `size`*. Also may want to set `render_target_v_flip` to `true`, this flips the image vertically. If you find the output **image is upside down** it is because you need to toggle `render_target_v_flip`.

Then place as child of the `Viewport` what you want to render.

---

**Rendering**

Next, you can read the texture form the `Viewport`, convert it to an image, and save it to a png. I'm doing this on a tool script attached to the `Viewport`, so I'll have a workaround to trigger the code from the inspector panel. My code looks like this:

```
tool
extends Viewport

export var save:bool setget do_save

func do_save(new_value) -> void:
    var image := get_texture().get_data()
    var error := image.save_png("res://output.png")
    if error != OK:
        push_error("failed to save output image.")
```

---

You can, of course, `export` a `FILE` path `String` to ease changing it in the inspector panel. Here I'm handing common edge cases:

```
tool
extends Viewport

export(String, FILE) var path:String
export var save:bool setget do_save

func do_save(_new_value) -> void:
    var target_path := path.strip_edges()
    var folder := target_path.get_base_dir()
    var file_name := target_path.get_file()
    var extension := target_path.get_extension()
    if file_name == "":
        push_error("empty file name.")
        return

    if not (Directory.new()).dir_exists(folder):
        push_error("output folder does not exist.")
        return

    if extension != "png":
        target_path += "png" if target_path.ends_with(".") else ".png"

    var image := get_texture().get_data()
    var error := image.save_png(target_path)
    if error != OK:
        push_error("failed to save output image.")
        return

    print("image saved to ", target_path)
```

---

Another option is to use `ResourceSaver`:

```
tool
extends Viewport

export var save:bool setget do_save

func do_save(new_value) -> void:
    var image := get_texture().get_data()
    var error := ResourceSaver.save("res://image.res", image)
    if error != OK:
        push_error("failed to save output image.")
```

This will only work from the Godot editor, and will only work for Godot, since you get a Godot resource file. Although I find interesting the idea of using Godot to generate images. I'm going to suggest going with `ResourceSaver` if you want to automate generating them for Godot.

---

### About saving resources from tool scripts

In the examples above, I'm assuming you are saving to a resource path. This is because the intention is to use the output image as a resource in Godot. Using a resource path has a couple implications:

1. This might not work on an exported game (since the goals is improve the workflow, this is OK).
2. Godot would need to re-import the resource, but will not notice it changed.

We can deal with the second point from an `EditorPlugin`, if that is what you are doing, you can do this to tell Godot to scan for changes:

```
get_editor_interface().get_resource_filesystem().scan()
```

And if you are not, you can cheat by creating an empty `EditorPlugin`. The idea is to do this:

```
var ep = EditorPlugin.new()
ep.get_editor_interface().get_resource_filesystem().scan()
ep.free()
```

By the way, you will want to cache cache the `EditorPlugin` instead of making a new one each time. Or better yet, cache the `EditorFileSystem` you get from `get_resource_filesystem`.

---

### Automation

Now, I'm aware that it can be cumbersome to have to place things inside the `Viewport`. It might be Ok for your workflow if you don't need to do it all the time.

But what about automating it? Well, regardless of the approach, you will need a `tool` script that makes a hidden `Viewport`, takes a `Node`, checks if it has a shader, if it does, it moves it temporarily to the `Viewport`, get the rendered texture (`get_texture()`) sets it as the texture of the `Node`, removes the shader, and returns the `Node` to its original position in the scene. *Or instead of looking for a shader in the *Node*, always apply a shader to whatever `Node`, perhaps loaded as a resource instead of hard-coded.*

**Note**: I believe you need to let an idle frame pass between adding the `Node` to the `Viewport` and getting the texture, so the texture updates. *Or was it two idle frames? Well, if one does not work, try adding another one.*

---

**About making an `EditorPlugin`**

As you know, you can create an addon from project settings. This will create an `EditorPlugin` script for you. There you can either add an option to the tools menu (with `add_tool_menu_item`), or add it to the tool bar of the editor (with `add_control_to_container`). And have it act on the current selection in the edited scene (you can either use `get_selection`, or overwrite the `edit` and `handles` methods). *You may also want to make an undo entry for that, see `get_undo_redo`.*

Or, alternatively you can have it keep track (or look for) the `Node`s it has to act upon, and then work on the `build` virtual method, which runs when the project is about to run. *I haven't worked with the `build` virtual method, so I don't know if it has any quirks to gotchas to be aware of.*