# How to force reimport of texture in godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a `sample.png` file which is being changed outside godot
and after it's modified, godot recives a signal and when that signal is received
I want that specific sample.png file to be reimported

I tried [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/p8o5he/triggerforce_reimport_of_png_file_from_script/) answer but I want to reimport in my script itself not create a plugin for it
(atleast that's what I'm assuming it does)

I also tried [this](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.4/classes/class_editorfilesystem.html#class-editorfilesystem-method-update-file) from the documents but I'm not sure how to use it exactly

```
EditorFileSystem.update_file("res://Assets/sample.png")
```

so how do I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `EditorFileSystem` is intended for plugins.

You would call `get_editor_interface()` from an `EditorPlugin` (which would be where you would be writing code if you were making a plugin). And that gives you an `EditorInterface` object, on which you can call `get_resource_filesystem()` which gives you an `EditorFileSystem` object.

So the intended use is something like this:

```
extends EditorPlugin

func example() -> void:
    var editor_file_system := get_editor_interface().get_resource_filesystem()
    editor_file_system.scan_sources()
    # editor_file_system.update_file("res://icon.png")
```

*By the way, `EditorInterface` also has a `filesystem_changed` signal. Although I don't know how reliable it is.*

Usually you don't have to do that. When you restore the Godot window, it will scan for changes in the project folder. So you might minimize Godot while you are working on something else and when you bring the Godot window back it will pick on the changes.

In practice, the only situations when I had to use `scan` or `scan_sources` was when I had a tool script that write a resource file which should be imported, and I wanted it to reflect right away.

---

Instead of making a custom plugin, I'll remind you that form a tool script (as long as it is running in the editor) you can simply create an `EditorPlugin` object. For example:

```
var ep = EditorPlugin.new()
ep.get_editor_interface().get_resource_filesystem().scan()
ep.free()
```

*I had also shared this example in another answer I wrote for you a while back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71259445/402022), it is under the title "About saving resources from tool scripts".*