# Apply shader to an Image & save without viewport?

Tags: godot, gdscript

With regards to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74177491/18005234),

Transparent images being generated are darker in shade as in this [issue](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/17574)
The given [solution](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/17574#issuecomment-1260414778) to that issue is to add this shader:

> ```
> shader_type canvas_item;
> render_mode blend_premul_alpha;
> ```

So I took the dark image created from viewport and added it into a `TextureRect` as a texture and applied the above shader

but how do I **generate** an image from this applied shader?

because the only way I found to save images with shaders are by [using viewports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71259445/18005234)
(which are causing the problem in the first place, like a recursive problem)

#### What am I trying to achieve?

I simply want the `viewport.get_texture().get_data().save_png("res://img.png")` image to not be dark in shade

#### Edit

This is what the `MergedImg` is suppose to look like:

[image]

This is how it actually ends up looking like :

[image]

Comment: I challenge that you need a shader. I had the issue of dark images. It happened to me because they were imported with "Detect 3D", which makes Godot re-import them if I used them as texture in anything 3D… Resulting in them being too dark when used in 2D. So I believe this is a import settings issue.

Comment: @Theraot I tried unchecking `Detect 3D` and then generating merge image but it doesn't seem to work, I made this [sample demo](https://file.io/7n2FvOHbNI3J) incase you'd like to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, the issue is that the image will have alpha multiplication done no matter what we do. And arguably it should not. I expected that setting Premultiplied Alpha in import settings would give us the correct result, *but it does not*※. Instead what works is telling Godot that the image has alpha pre-multiplied via a material/shader… But we don't want to have to do that!

So, as workaround we will fall to alpha division (unmultiplication?). *You might not want to do this on image that has lossy compression, because it could reveal compression artifacts. Thankfully that is not the case here.*

The code is like this:

```
    var mergeImg=screenshot_viewport.get_texture().get_data()
    mergeImg.lock()
    for y in mergeImg.get_size().y:
        for x in mergeImg.get_size().x:
            var color:Color = mergeImg.get_pixel(x, y)
            if color.a != 0:
                mergeImg.set_pixel(x, y, Color(color.r / color.a, color.g / color.a, color.b / color.a, color.a))

    mergeImg.unlock()
    mergeImg.save_png(img_path)
```

And with that the saved image won't have alpha multiplication applied. So we should not tell Godot it has it, so we don't need to use a material to do so.

---

※: It does the opposite of what we want, it multiplies alpha again.